How to connect heaters and RTD sensors from an EMC perspective
I have a PCB that drives an external system with simple resistance heaters and Resistance Temperature Detector (RTD) sensors for temperature readings placed close to them. The PCB includes a typical RTD reading circuit (op-amp, ADC, etc.).
What is the best option to connect the heaters and sensors from an EMC perspective?
The options that are feasible due to cable routing are:

One connector (one cable) that contains all of the signals. In this case, I am concerned about the power supply and return current of the heater potentially interfering with the analog signal of the RTD.
Two separate connectors, so two cables: one for the heater and one for the sensor.

Which option is better to minimize EMI and ensure accurate readings from the RTD sensors?

The resistance heaters could be made to be very low noise depending on how you drive them.

Do you envision the one connector would have three pins (heater, RTD, common ground)?  Have you considered splitting the ground? What about the environment, are emissions a concern? What about nearby sources, how much noise might this controller be exposed to?

@TimWilliams the environment is a closed grounded metal container. What i am concerned about having one connector and the 4 wires, is if the small analog signal of the RTD can be distorted, by the supply and return current of the heater, causing faults in temp measurements

"Distorted" is a very different question; by what mechanism would nonlinearity occur? If you mean more collquially that the waveform looks different, what aspects of the waveform would you need -- what bandwidth are you expecting from this system? (It's not stated in the question, and I would assume fractional Hz, maybe 10s of Hz at best, for a thermostat.) In contrast, what frequencies would you expect induced from the heater?

Generally you want to run the low level signals separately and perhaps shielded. Aside from EMI, depending on your jurisdiction there are safety regulations that may require more or different insulation on the low level wires than you would otherwise prefer.
If the heaters are being switched with a relay there will be more EMI than if you are using solid-state switching.
Usually you'd prefer a different kind of connector for the heaters than for the sensors (high current and voltage ratings, precious metal plating unimportant, etc. )
RTDs are relatively high level (especially compared to thermocouples), are almost always floating, and relatively slow, therefore it's relatively easy to design a front end that is EMI-resistant. In a regular industrial situation where a few degrees C are unimportant, it's not a big deal, however if you're looking for unusually fast response time by thermal standards and millidegree C performance that could be different. This is rare and atypical of industrial equipment.
That said, sometimes (as in 'hot runner' controls for plastic molding) it's desirable to be able to connect a large number of sensors and heaters quickly and without risk of errors by setup persons. In such cases, sometimes connectors are joined together as so (and with a compromise on connector type - since this is not a very demanding application precision-wise):

